# UI based on individual data / dynamic / generative

Tags: layout, data, color-scheme, typography

I am looking for examples where the UI is designed based on the individual user data. Not just a customizable profile page, more automated individual color palette / layout / typography / ??? depending on individual user attributes like age, friends etc.

Do you know any examples in that direction?

*edited for clarity:*

on the apple app store, some apps have a unique page which is derived from the color palette of their app icon. Imagine your Facebook ui would look different from your friend's in terms of color, layout / size and placement of ui elements, typefont – and all of this would be derived from your profile data. you are from new york – times new roman, you are from LA – Helvetica. you have 516 friends – red primary color, you have 1208 friends – blue primary color –

Comment: You'll need to be more clear about your question.

Comment: So there you have it? Apple store is an example I guess. But what do you mean by automatic? I can't think of any examples, but it seems like you have enough details in your head to build a prototype, no?

Comment: Hi @LrnzLngg! Your comment adds some good context to the question, please add it using the "edit" button. :)

Comment: If you are designing something like this I would be very interested! I think perhaps a tag based file management system like TagSpaces (https://www.tagspaces.org/) has the potential to be made into something like what you are talking about because it has a dynamic way of dealing with how content is structured and organized.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question because I imagine that most of the design philosophy and design systems are geared towards creating interchangeable modules that can provide a great deal of flexibility and adaptability at the application level to conform with a specific look & feel (i.e. brand), and so I don't think they would be very useful for designing something that allows for such a fine grained level of individual customization.

I can think of design strategies that can adapt the way content is presented to the user based on their usage data, or surfacing functions or features based on usage statistics or recommendation engine, but nothing in the way of user interface presentation. The closest to what you are talking about would probably be a customizable 'dashboard' or home page to a site.

Alternatively, you can actually think of CMS such as WordPress as a platform that basically has a set of core functionalities but you can modify all aspects using plugins. Other than that I can't think of any examples. Perhaps with the emergence of blockchain-based applications we might see some new paradigms for UI design along those lines, or the conversational interfaces that make use of VR or AR features could cope with this better as some of the physical design constraints are removed.

I would be interested to find out if anyone else has come across an example or two.

Comment: Some of the design strategies you describe are obvious examples I didn't think of – the newsfeed, of course:)

What I am looking for is less 'adaption for streamlined user experience / business purposes', which also in most cases is designed to be not recognized by the user, more explicit data / behaviour visualization through UI. At the same time, it should adapt automatically, unlike a customizable dashboard.

Comment: @LrnzLngg as I said before I can't really think of any examples along what you are referring to but I think it might be a combination of technical and design related bottlenecks preventing it from happening. But now that I know about it, I will be keeping an eye out for it and thinking about it :)